# How to display an svg image coming from inputstream in android?

Tags: android, svg

How can an svg xml string be displayed as an image in android? The examples that I have come across load the already existing images present in the drawable folder but whereas in my case the svg data is in a string?.

Comment: Did you found any work around to this issue ?